# Retrieving HTML Source Code using - MAC VBA Word 2011

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, ms-office

Below Is my Code to read source code from websites on windows operating system.

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
URL = "http://webste.com"   'Replace http://webste.com with your own website.
objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.send ("")
HTML = objHTTP.responseText
```

I would like to find something similar for Mac VBA Word 2011. I've been trying for days to find something that will work for Mac to no avail. Please if you have a link to another post or some code that works let me know. Preferably code that works without downloading anything, so it works on any Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worthy to say that this [information](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macexcel/need-xmlhttp-request-like-feature-in-excel-for-mac/f2b5aca7-fcbb-4c60-b606-27e1c4a0fcd9) goes back to the 2012, so maybe something has changed meanwhile.

As for what the MVP of the question above says, `ActiveX` is a Windows-only technology that has not been ported to Mac (yet?), so the `XMLHTTP` request initialization will fail with a run-time error `ActiveX component cannot create object`.
You might be interested in using a [Web Query](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;274787), which is instead usable by a Mac according to the Microsoft Official source.